# Is there a Scala function of type `Nothing => A`? Or how to construct one?

Tags: scala, unit-type, curry-howard

Through [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry-Howard_Isomorphism) Scala's `Unit` corresponds to logical true and `Nothing` to logical false. The fact that logical true is implied by anything is witnessed by a simple function that just discards the argument:

```
def toUnit[A](x: A): Unit = { }
```

Is there a function that witnesses the fact that logical false implies anything, that is a function of type `Nothing => A`? Or is there an idiomatic way how to construct one?

One can always do something like

```
def fromNothing[A](n: Nothing): A = throw new RuntimeException();
```

but this is just ugly - it doesn't use the fact that `Nothing` has no values. There should be a way how to do it without exceptions.

Comment: Shouldn't the top type (i.e. Any) be true ?

Comment: @Jamil Yes, we could take `Any` to be logical true as well. From the CH perspective, they're equivalent, because we can easily construct witnessing functions `(_ => ()) : Any => Unit` and `identity : Unit => Any`.

Comment: @Jamil In CH correspondence we don't compare two types `A` and `B` according to type hierarchy, we compare them according to the existence of a function of type `A => B`. So if we didn't have type hierarchy (like in Haskell) then still any empty data type would correspond to _false_ and any one-element data type would correspond to _true_. If we have a type hierarchy and `A` is a subtype of `B` then we have `identity: A => B` so 'A' corresponds to a stronger proposition than `B`. But we can have `f: A => B` even though `A` is not a subtype of `B`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do that

```
def emptyFunction[A]: Nothing => A = {n => n}
```

or

```
def emptyFunction[A](n: Nothing): A = n
```

Comment: Oh very nice. I didn't realize that as `Nothing` is a subtype of anything I can simply use it in place of `A`.